# Select random number from string of 1's and 0's and change color

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have a string of random 1's and 0's displayed via jQuery.  I would now like to select a random number and change it's color.  Is it better to work with an array, or a $(div).text() string?  I can grab a number from either, but how do I insert it back into the div?

```
 var numbArray = [];

 for(i=0; i<10; i++)
 {
   var randomNumbers = Math.round(Math.random());
   $('#numbs').prepend(randomNumbers);
   numbArray[i] = randomNumbers;
 }

<div id="numbs">0000110111 </div>
```

The div above is the result of the code, but how do I select a random item, change its color, and display in the original output?

Thanks,

Comment: You are changing text color based on the total binary sum of the random number? I suggest using the array since it's already has numbers, then assign you selection to something like `var bin` and then `$('#numbs').text(bin)`

Comment: _ insert it back into the div_ means ?

Answer (score 1):

You can locate the number at a certain index, wrap it with the desired color and rebuild the string and set it back to the div using `html()` and use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)` to generate the random number from zero to the length of the characters you have.

```js
var index = 3;
var originalElementValue;

function colorStringValue(strIndex)
{
  strIndex = parseInt(strIndex);
  
  var character = originalElementValue.charAt(strIndex);
  $("#numbs").html(originalElementValue.substr(0, strIndex) + "<span style='color:red'>" + character + "</span>" +  originalElementValue.substr(strIndex+1));
  
  }



$(document).ready(function(){

  originalElementValue = $("#numbs").text();
  colorStringValue(index);
  
  $("#strIndex").click(function(){
  
       var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 0  ;
    $("#rand").html(rand);
        colorStringValue(rand);
  
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="strIndex" > Generate Random Number </button>
<br />

Random Number : <span id="rand"></span>

<br />

<div id="numbs">0000110111</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick a random index from the number string and append some element around that particular number to give it some style.

```js
var number = '0000110111';

var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * number.length);

for(var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  var n = number.charAt(i);
  if(i == index) {
    $('#numbs').append($('<span/>').css('color', 'red').text(n));
  } else {
    $('#numbs').append(n);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numbs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbArray = [];

for(i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    var randomNumbers = Math.round(Math.random());
    numbArray[i] = randomNumbers;
    $('#numbs').prepend(number);
}
var randomNumberSelection = numbArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * (numbArray.length-1)) + 1)];

$('#numbs').html("");

var number;
for(number in numbArray) {
    if(number == randomNumberSelection) {
        var colorColorCodedNumber = ""+number;
            colorColorCodedNumber = colorColorCodedNumber.fontcolor("blue");//blue!
        $('#numbs').prepend(colorColorCodedNumber);
    } else {
        $('#numbs').prepend(number);
    }
}
```

I believe you're looking for something along the lines of this, or at least this is what I took from what you were asking.

In this example be aware you'll see we clear the element then simply reiterate over the array you stored earlier. That is how you 'update' it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right you want to set a color for a specific position in the div. This means you have to create a span (or another html-element) inside the div at at a random position with a specific color. I havent tested this code below but I guess you could something like this: (in this example red color for the random item)

```
var randomIndex= Math.floor(Math.random() * 9); //Random number between 0 and 9.
var currentContent = $("#numbs").html(); 
var randomItem= currentContent.charAt(randomIndex);

newContent = '';
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (i == randomIndex) {
        newContent = newContent + 
        '<span style="background:red;">' + randomItem + '</span>';
    }
    else {
        newContent = newContent + currentContent.charAt(i);
    }
}

$("#numbs").html( newContent );
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? I just gave it a try. :)

```
     var numbArray = [];
     var sample = "<span style='color:#%COLOR%'>%NUM%</span>";
     for(i=0; i<10; i++)
     {
       var randomNumbers = Math.round(Math.random());
       var html = sample.replace('%NUM%', randomNumbers);
       var randomColor = Math.round((Math.random()* 100000000 )%16777215).toString(16);
       html = html.replace('%COLOR%', randomColor);
       $('#numbs').prepend(html );
       numbArray[i] = randomNumbers;
     }
```

I assumed that you want random colors too.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers by all; thanks!  I didn't think of appending the DOM and redisplaying.  I went with assigning each number an id and then using css without appending. I was looking for numbers that would turn a color and when all the numbers were that color the script would stop.  I don't know which method would perform the best but this way is okay for my limited numbers.

```
var whiteNumbs =
[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]

for(var i=0; i<whiteNumbs.length; i++) 
{
    $("#numbs").append('<span class="white" id="num_' + i + '">' +
     whiteNumbs[i] + '</span>');
}

function MakeRed()
{
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * whiteNumbs.length-1);

    var changeCSS = "#num_" + randomNumber;

    $(changeCSS).removeClass('white');
    $(changeCSS).addClass("red");

if ($("#numbs span").hasClass("white") )
{
    setTimeout(MakeRed,1000);
}
else
{
    return false;   
}

};

MakeRed();
```